# Export Eclipse RCP Product -> "Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.views"

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, rcp

I develop a feature based RCP application (using gef and draw2d) in Eclipse Mars and I want to generate an executable out of the product. For this I use the "Eclipse Product export wizard". But there is an error, when I start the executable:

```
!SESSION 2016-06-28 13:54:38.816 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_92
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
Framework arguments:  -clearPersistedState
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -clearPersistedState

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.app 0 0 2016-06-28 13:54:40.239
!MESSAGE Product interfaces.interfaces could not be found.

!ENTRY interfaces 2 0 2016-06-28 13:54:40.596
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: interfaces [3]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.views


!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-06-28 13:54:40.598
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI$URIPool$PlatformAccessUnit.setValue(URI.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI$URIPool.intern(URI.java:1949)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI.createPlatformPluginURI(URI.java:2718)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.determineApplicationModelURI(E4Application.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.loadApplicationModel(E4Application.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
```

I think the problem is that not all required libraries/plug-ins are included in the generated folder.

The same error occurs when I try to start the application via "product -> Overview tab -> Launch an Eclipse application".
This problem can be solved by clicking "Run Configuarions -> Plug-ins -> Add Required Plug-ins".
I assume that those Plug-ins which are added by "Add Required Plug-ins" are missing to run the executable.

Can anyone tell me, how to tell eclipse to include them when building the executable? Or am I missing something else?

I have already checked all boxes in "plug-in -> Build -> Binary Build/Source Build". I have also tried to include the missing libraries in the Build Tab. But nothing seems to work :/

thanks!

Thomas

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using an xxx.product file for your build. You need to go to the 'Contents' tab and click 'Add Required' to add the required plugins (or features) to the build.

This is separate from the 'Run Configuration' plugin configuration.

Comment: I can't even go through IDE! How should I go to Content tab?!

Comment: @Mr.Hyde Sorry, but I have no idea what you are asking. Please ask a new question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the fast response!

Your hint gave me the clue to find the answer.

I had to add

- org.eclipse.ui
- org.eclipse.help
- org.eclipse.gef
- ...

to the 'Included Plug-ins' Tab within my feature (which I include in my product).

Thanks!